# Django - Built in reset password links not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I was following this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html) on implementing the built in Django reset password views. I am using a custom User Model and I have read that when a user model inherits from AbstractUser, it should work with the password reset views as normal. However, none of them work. I am trying to access the reset form and nothing is displayed. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Model

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

urls

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

templates

```
registration/password_reset_complete.html
registration/password_reset_confirm.html
registration/password_reset_done.html
registration/password_reset_email.html
registration/password_reset_form.html
registration/password_reset_subject.txt
```

Email backend for development

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the console backend for email backend. Check your terminal, if your on Mac, Linux, on windows check your console, you could copy the link from the console and paste in your browser.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain properly. The form in  "password_reset_form.html" is not rendering on the template at all. So I haven't got near the email stage of the process.

Comment: Did you set template directory in settings.py?

Comment: Yeah my templates work fine with every other form I have within my application. I haven't touched my template settings since I created the app

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have all relevant tags loaded in the template so the form was not rendering. In my case I had the include the following at the top:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block nav_title %}Title{% endblock %}
{% block body_content %}
```

I thought I had them in before but perhaps I didn't.